Google Cloud OAuth Error which is giving error related to COOP( cross origin opener policy)
I am working a  MERN project and here is the code for implementing Google authentication button
enter image description here
and in output it opens the pop up window for authentication but when I click on one email address to login.... it displays the following:
enter image description here
I checked the client id which is same, there is no error thereenter image description here
